# How to add Any Authenticated AWS User Group to the New S3 Console

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have been using the old S3 console to set permissions for downloads. During uploads I would be prompted to set permissions and could check the box open/download for Any Authenticated AWS User. I was also able to click on properties and open permissions and check the same box.

I am unable to find anything similar for the new console. It appears I can only either grant read access to everyone or not. How do I create a group for Authenticated AWS Users so I can grant open/download access?

Amazon sent me an email yesterday stating they notice I still use the old console and it will no longer be available to use after the end of this month so I really need to figure out how to set the proper permissions in the new console.

Thanks

Comment: You do realize that "any" authenticated user means *in any AWS account* -- not just your account -- right?

Comment: Why do you wish to authorize *Any Authenticated AWS user*?

Comment: I do understand that. MY S3 Woocommerce plugin handles that. I have always set the downloads to this setting. This is the instruction from Woocommerce "It is critical that if you want to make files private that when you upload them to Amazon through the AWS console you select that the file is for Authenticated Users, if it’s set to Everybody the file will be available to everybody with a link."